# Change contents of a modal without closing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Suppose I have a series of modals in same page opened by clicking on different pictures. 2 of them like this:

```
<!-- FIRST MODAL -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title boldfont">THIS IS MODAL 1 HEADER</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="images/lorem1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <p class="modaltext">Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean.</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- SECOND MODAL-->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal2" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title boldfont">THIS IS MODAL 2 HEADER</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="images/lorem2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <p class="modaltext">Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean.</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now after a modal is opened, to switch the next picture the user has to close the modal and click on another picture. I want the user to be able to click somewhere on the currently open modal and switch to the next modal's content without closing it.

I added the following code into footer but it looks bad since it closes the modal and animates a new one in. I just want the content to change.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal2">next</button>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not possible with pure Bootstrap. You can use this plugin for stackable modals. http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/

Comment: You can add a carousel inside the modal. or use lightbox plugin. - http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant, but here's how I've managed to achieve your request plus toggling back and forth.

1. Add another button to the footer of Modal1
2. Add another button to the footer of Modal2
3. Add the following script to your javascript for 3

## 1

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="nextMod()">Go to Modal 2</button>
```

## 2

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="priorMod()">Return to Modal 1</button>
```

## 3

```
function nextMod() {
        $("#modal2").show();
        $("#modal1").hide();
    }
function priorMod() {
        $("#modal1").show();
        $("#modal2").hide();

    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry meant to say that the show and hide are referencing two different divs that contain the header, body, and footer of the two modals.  Both are contained within the same Modal.  set the second div to have a style of display:none.